# возникает ошибка после переопределия оператора =

Tags: c++

перегрузил оператор =

```
void operator = (Vector &other) {
        this->angle = other.angle;
        this->length = other.length;
    }
```

когда вызываю его то возникает ошибка

**No viable overloaded '='**

строка на которой возникает ошибка

`B1 = B2 + B3;`

тоже перегружен оператор +

```cpp
Vector operator + (Vector &other) {
        double a1 = this->angle * M_PI / 180;
        double a2 = other.angle * M_PI / 180;

        double x1 = this->length * cos(a1);
        double y1 = this->length * sin(a1);
        double x2 = other.length * cos(a2);
        double y2 = other.length * sin(a2);

        double x3 = x1 + x2;
        double y3 = y1+y2;

        return {length = sqrt(x3*x3 + y3*y3), angle = atan2(y3, x3)};
    }
```

Comment: Параметр должен быть константной ссылкой. И у `operator+` тоже. Еще, обычно у `operator=` ставят возвращаемый тип `Vector &`, и делают `return *this;`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите - вы из оператора `+` возвращаете `Vector` - т.е. временное значение, rvalue. Но в

```
void operator = (Vector &other)
```

вы говорите, что справа от `=` должно стоять lvalue, что вы будете его менять (да, *реально* вы его менять не будете, но из *сигнатуры* следует, что планируете это делать).

Т.е. у вас получается ситуация наподобие

```
f(int& x) { x = 5; }
```

с вызовом

```
f(3)
```

Вы же не можете менять литерал 3? :)

Так что объясняйте своему оператору, что вы не планируете менять передаваемое значение

```
void operator = (const Vector &other) {
```

Ну, конечно, есть еще вариант - передача по значению

```
void operator = (Vector other) {
```

но это уж совсем некрасиво...